# How do I work with a master SIR equation?

Tags: modeling, markov-process

Using the definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model) and a standard Markov chain, I arrived at the following master equation:
$$\partial_t P_{S,I,R}(t) = (\beta/N)(I-1)(S+1)P_{S+1,I-1,R}(t) + \gamma(I+1)P_{S,I+1,R-1}(t)-(\beta IS/N+\gamma I)P_{S,I,R}(t)$$
It's awful, but the real problem is I'm not sure on what to do with this. I want to plot $I(t)$ (and the other params) but I don't know how to do this with my result. Since all I have are probabilities, I guessed I can plot the expected-value functions:

$$\bar{I}(t)=\sum_{i}iP_{S,i,R}(t)$$

but getting $P_{S,i,R}$ does not look easy. I thought about approximating $P$ in an Euler-step manner but I noticed that the $\partial_t P_{S,I,R}$ term as an $P_{S,I,R}$ dependence itself so this doesn't look right. This getting complex, and I think I'm heading in the wrong direction. Any advice?